# React gives an error when returning JSON data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React and Cockpit-project.org API to get physical server status. I get a right string in my console when it returns the status, but the problem is that I want this to be shown in my page instead of console, and I have a button property for this to do exactly the same as my componentDidMount() method does. Here is my code:

```
"use strict";

const output = document.getElementById("output");


class CockpitTest extends React.Component {

  getOutput(data) {
    output.append(document.createTextNode(data));
  }

  async componentDidMount(){
    await cockpit.spawn(["/usr/local/bin/statusdemo"])
    .stream(this.getOutput)
    var myArray = JSON.parse(output.innerHTML);
    console.log(myArray.psu1.status);
    console.log(myArray.psu2.status);
    console.log(myArray.mgmt1);
    console.log(myArray.mgmt2);
    console.log(myArray.data1);
    console.log(myArray.data2);
  }

  async showStatus() {
    await cockpit.spawn(["/usr/local/bin/statusdemo"])
    .stream(this.getOutput)
    var myArray = JSON.parse(output.innerHTML);
    console.log(myArray.psu1.status);
    console.log(myArray.psu2.status);
    console.log(myArray.mgmt1);
    console.log(myArray.mgmt2);
    console.log(myArray.data1);
    console.log(myArray.data2);
    return (
      <ul>
        {myArray.map((data, i) => (
          <li key={i}>{data.text}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }

  render() {
      return (
       <div>
         <button onClick={this.showStatus}>SHOW SERVER STATUS</button>
       </div>
);
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <CockpitTest />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

but in this button case I get an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getOutput' of null.

So my question would be why doesn't my code throw this error when mounting the component? And why does it  when using a button method? I'm confused...

Comment: I am not quite sure what does `cockpit.spawn().stream` do but the cause of the error is in usage `this`. Try replacing `async showStatus()` with arrow function declaration
( `showStatus = async () => { ....}` ) .
It will prevent `this` to point another context while passed to `button`s `onClick` prop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind showStatus in your constructor. The component lifecycle methods are so bound by default.

You need to add a constructor like so:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.showStatus = this.showStatus.bind(this);
}
```

Without doing so 'this' will be null in that method.

Comment: Thanks, but now it gives me a new error: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 361.
What could be the problem here?

Comment: I'm not sure since there's no context in your post explaining what cockpit.spawn does, but on the face of it it sounds like you're trying to parse malformed JSON.

Answer (score 0):

i will explain how this work with react, first let's take this example:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
 hi(){
 console.log("hi")
  }
  click() {
    console.log(this);
    this.hi();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <button onClick={this.click}>click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

here this example will give an error because the click function got different scope then the `hi()` function if you try to see `console.log(this)` this will return the show global window object so if we do this :

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

window.hi = () => {
  console.log("hi");
};

class App extends React.Component {
  click() {
    console.log(this);
    this.hi();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <button onClick={this.click}>click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

now it will work because the function `click` environment is the global window. in this case this work ok but what if you got to manage component state in your click function here where this will not work because state is only for `react.Component` and that why you need to bind the `click` to the component scope so that it will be able to access React.component methods and you can do this with several ways but i prefer arrow function auto binding like this :

```
 click =()=> {
    console.log(this);
    this.hi();
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

In React you return entire component tree you want to render in the `render` method. In your case you return React nodes in the asynchronous callback of click handler. Basically they are ignored.
To fix this you need to save network call result like this: `this.setState({myArray: myArray})` and then in `render` method you would check if `myArray` is present in the state and if present render it.